# How to split strings into characters in Scala

Tags: string, scala, character-encoding, split, character

For example, there is a string val `s = "Test"`. How do you separate it into `t, e, s, t`?

Comment: What output is needed? You can just convert it to list S.toList Output List[Char] = List(T, e, s, t)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `toList` as follows:

```
scala> s.toList         
res1: List[Char] = List(T, e, s, t)
```

If you want an array, you can use `toArray`

```
scala> s.toArray
res2: Array[Char] = Array(T, e, s, t)
```

Comment: For those seeing this, toCharArray should always be preferred when possible. toList is painfully slow. Each character primitive becomes a Character object. Each link in the list is an object as well. 2 bytes becomes 12+2+12+2=28 bytes. We can no longer have quick and random access. However, if you are just playing around or writing Hello World, then have at it, but don't expect it to scale well.

Comment: I am new to Scala. Why does `"abc".toList` work but `"abc".toList()` doesn't work. Where can I find documentation for scala String.

Comment: Found the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643030/what-is-the-rule-for-parenthesis-in-scala-method-invocation, never mind.

Answer (score 71):

Do you need characters?

```
"Test".toList    // Makes a list of characters
"Test".toArray   // Makes an array of characters
```

Do you need bytes?

```
"Test".getBytes  // Java provides this
```

Do you need strings?

```
"Test".map(_.toString)    // Vector of strings
"Test".sliding(1).toList  // List of strings
"Test".sliding(1).toArray // Array of strings
```

Do you need UTF-32 code points?  Okay, that's a tougher one.

```
def UTF32point(s: String, idx: Int = 0, found: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = {
  if (idx >= s.length) found.reverse
  else {
    val point = s.codePointAt(idx)
    UTF32point(s, idx + java.lang.Character.charCount(point), point :: found)
  }
}
UTF32point("Test")
```

Comment: For even being aware of code points, you deserve to have the accepted answer here.  Though I doubt the OP will appreciate the subtlety.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you don't need to do anything special. There is already implicit conversion  in `Predef` to `WrappedString` and `WrappedString` extends `IndexedSeq[Char]` so you have all goodies that available in it, like:

```
"Test" foreach println
"Test" map (_ + "!")
```

#### Edit

`Predef` has `augmentString` conversion that has higher priority than `wrapString` in `LowPriorityImplicits`. So String end up being `StringLike[String]`, that is also `Seq` of chars.

Comment: I think it goes via `StringOps` actually.

Comment: @Kevin Wright: You are right. `Predef` has `augmentString` conversion that has higher priority than `wrapString` in `LowPriorityImplicits`. Sorry for this, I don't noticed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, it should be noted that if what you actually want isn't an actual list object, but simply to do something which each character, then Strings can be used as iterable collections of characters in Scala

```
for(ch<-"Test") println("_" + ch + "_") //prints each letter on a different line, surrounded by underscores
```